# SEO keywords in sites with query string parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, seo

Im using one template for all my products sites:

www.mySite.com/Products.aspx?productId=x

where x is product id :)

Now I can add keywords to my Products.apsx page but Im wondering if its posssible to add descriptions and keywords to all sites with ?ProductId=x so that user may find direct link to certainn product page based for example by product name which would be in keywords for given page.

THanks for any help

Comment: Are you talking about a 2nd URL structure including a product name, i.e. ?ProductId=my_product_name ..?

Answer (score 0):

First off you are probably better off doing some url rewriting to get the product name into the url, for example change

```
www.mysite.com/products.aspx?productid=x
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/product/productname
```

Have a read through one of the millions of seo guides on the web and make sure you are doing as much of it as possible, see [dev mooses guide](http://devmoose.com/blogging/10-basic-seo-tips-every-web-developer-should-follow) for a decent example.

You can add the product name and short description into the url title, h1 tags on the page, and into the meta tags for keywords and description.

Hope this helps

Comment: ok but when should I add this meta tags ? When page is rendering or when ?

Comment: yeah you add the meta tags programmatically by directly accessing the head section, or if your using master pages than create a content section in the header which you can set from your product pages, do it just after you load the product details in the page load.